# Trouble converting DateTime (.net) to datetime (SQL server)

Tags: vb.net, parameters, .net-4.0, sql-server-2012, sqlcommand

I'm trying to pass a string (from a text file) - '17/07/99' into a sql server table - the destination is a date column.
the insert is in a string, of the form:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(...yada...) 
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO my.table (thisDate, ...etc... ) VALUES (@myDate, ...etc...)"
```

I am adding the parameters to the cmd using:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.ParseExact("11/11/11", "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

When I come to `ExecuteNonQuery`

I get `cannot convert string to datetime` error.
I thought the ParseExact was doing the conversion from string to DateTime??

Do I really need to do a CONVERT in the sql as well as using datetime structures ?!

Comment: I should add that I had been using .Value = CType("11/11/11", DateTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2011, 11, 11);
```

And also see this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Same - couldnt convert from string to datetime. I'm refiguring the code to try and deal with the incoming data slightly differently. I intend to use ints to hold the year/month/day from the file, then push those through using new datetime(year, month, day).

Comment: Resolved! This was the one that worked - the problem was the idiot behind the wheel... ;) another parameter had got set (somehow) to sqldbtype.datetime when I was passing it a string of colour names!

Comment: Excelent! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

just tested this and it works ... you only need to format your date if you want it consistent no matter what culture your OS is otherwise you don't have to do that

you can use this way

```
Dim d As Date = "17/07/99"
```

or you can use this way

```
Dim d As Date = "17.07.99"
```

if you only have date without time then it doesn't matter what you use
you can either use this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d
```

or this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d
```

i just tried both versions mixed and no error whatsoever and rows inserted

Comment: That is indeed the issue - the test version I first wrote worked fine on my machine, but when I transferred to a live server, it broke - the server seems to be set using American date formats, causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try formatting the string before adding it.

```
Format(YourTimeStringHere, dd-MM-yy)
```

Comment: Don't encourage use of the legacy VB `Format` function.  Use `String.Format` instead.